# Does directly assigning a string of char's to a char pointer on initialization automatically add a null terminator?

Tags: c, string

For example in this code:

```
char *ptr = "string";
```

Is there a null terminator in the stored in the `ptr[6]` address?

When I test this and print a string, it prints "string", and if I print the `ptr[6]` char I get ''. I wanted to test this further so I did some research and found someone saying that strlen will always crash if there is not a null terminator. I ran this in my code and it returned 6, so does this mean that assigning a string to a char pointer initializes with a null terminator or am I misunderstanding what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. String literals used as pointers will always end in a `NUL` byte. String literals used as array initializers will too, unless you specify a length that's too small for it to (e.g., `char arr[] = "string";` and `char arr[7] = "string";` both will, but `char arr[6] = "string";` won't).

Comment: Does strlen() always crash if there isn't a null term, or is that just conditional to your memory layout?

Comment: @neutron02 Calling `strlen` on an unterminated string is Undefined Behavior. There's not a guarantee it will always crash. In practice, it will crash unless there happens to be some other zero byte in memory somewhere between the string and the next unmapped page.

Comment: thanks for the help, I keep finding myself coming back to the basics while on my C journey

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: "will crash unless there happens to be some other zero byte in memory" This is correct, but it's worth pointing out that, in practice, there almost always will be. You can't rely on it (so assume "it will crash" when writing code), but "`strlen` doesn't crash" is not a good test for "does my code do termination right".